# Registering / Installing a .NET 4 Assembly to the GAC

Tags: .net, gac

I am trying to test out assemblies and GAC in .NET 4.0. I have created two very basic class libraries, once in C++ and one in C#. Both of which are strong named. When I use the gacutil i- , I receive an output of registration successful. When I run gacutil -l , I can see that both my assemblies are installed in the GAC. However, when I try to load these assemblies using Reflection in C# / VBScript, it fails. I tried registering the assemblies with regasm /tbl  but this failed with the error "RegAsm : error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly ". What am I missing? Do I really need to register .NET 4 assemblies after installing them into the GAC? Any clarifications on this will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Since the assemblies install to the GAC and you can list them successfully, it seems most likely that the problem exists in your code that is reflecting on the assemblies. We need more information to help. What errors are you getting when reflecting on these assemblies? Can you post a sample of the code you're using to reflect on these assemblies?

Comment: @pmartin - thanks. I am indeed using the 4.0 version of gacutil. Basically, I created an empty class library in Visual Studio 10. I called it asm4 and it has a class named Class1. I created a key-pair keys with sn -k command and added it to my assembly with [assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("keyfile.snk")]. Compiled successfully and registered successfully with gacutil. Could you maybe post a sample assembly in 4.0 that does work? Thanks!

Comment: When you say you are looking in the GAC are you looking in c:\windows\assembly or C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly? .NET 4 does not use the old windows\assembly folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is very bizarre. I used this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/usedllgac.aspx.
Compiled it for .NET 4. The gacutil -i works since when I execute gacutil -l I can see my assembly. When I use their example to load the assembly I get an exception that the assembly or one of its dependencies were not found. Anything I am missing? When you use gacutil to install an assembly to the GAC, do you also need to register it with regasm?

Thanks!